# Handling errors (such as EADDRINUSE) with server.listen()

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, server

I have always been confused that `server.listen()` does not take an error-first callback:

```
server.listen(port, function(){
   // the first argument is *not* a potential error 
});
```

It must have been a tough design decision to not pass an error to the callback to listen().

It seems like we should handle errors here:

```
server.on('error', (e) => {
  if (e.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.log('Address in use, retrying...');
  }
});
```

but my concern is that `server.on('error'`) may fire several times, not just when the server starts up. It would be much more convenient if `EADDRINUSE` type errors were raised and passed back to the `server.listen()` callback.

Is there some pattern I can use to pass back errors, in a situation like so:

```
exports.startServer = function(data, cb){
   server.listen(data, cb);
   server.once('error', cb);
});
```

is the above code safe, so that cb will only fired once?

**It's not safe!** Because we need to remove the 'error' listener, like so:

```
exports.startServer = function(data, cb){
   let onError = function(err){
       cb(err);
    };

   server.once('error', onError);

   server.listen(data, function(){
      server.removeListener('error', onError);
      cb(null);
   });

});
```

I am hoping that the last example works, but is there a better pattern to handle this?